# Html Extension two properties from model with lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I need to call an HTML helper passing two properties from the model. The problem is when i try this:

```
 @Html.BsDropDownFor(x => x.Type.Id, x => x.Type.Descripcion, (IEnumerable<TextValue>)ViewBag.ClaseB)
```

the header method is defined like this:

```
  public static MvcHtmlString BsDropDownFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
      Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expressionValue,
      Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expressionText,
      IEnumerable<TextValue> items)
```

If I define

```
BsDropDownFor<TModel,TProperty>
```

doing is expected the same property in both arguments.

how should I define the method for receive two properties?

Updated 03-03-2015

Well my extension finally work

changed my signature for

```
  public static MvcHtmlString BsDropDownFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                                           Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
                                           string elementIdText,
                                           IEnumerable<TextValue> items)
```

expressionText is establish for other extension method and on the view is called

```
@Html.BsDropDownFor(x => x.Type.Id, Html.ModelPropertyTagId( x => x.Type.Descripcion), (IEnumerable<TextValue>)ViewBag.ClaseB)
```

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need separate type arguments for the two properties:

```
public static MvcHtmlString BsDropDownFor<TModel, TValue, TText>(
       this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
       Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expressionValue,
       Expression<Func<TModel, TText>> expressionText,
       IEnumerable<TextValue> items)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: i expected found some how @Html... ( new [] {x =>x.Type.Id, x => x.Type.Description}, .. other parameters ), thank you JLRishe

Comment: you right, after the refactor the code add two type arguments and the HtmlProperties too, thanks JLRishe